# DotNetNuke 5 open aspx in new window

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

Another issue I have in DNN5:

I'm currently creating a module that shows a GridView that has a "Edit" column.
When user clicks on "Edit" column, it should open an edit form in a new window.
This edit form is an ASPX-page inside my module folder and it expects a ModuleId parameter in order to access the module Settings; that part works fine and I'm able to retrieve the Module settings.

However, I still have the following issues:

1. **How can I localize my Labels?** I have tried DNN's label control, but no success. I also tried asp:Label with "meta:resourceKey", but it looks like it isn't able to access the local resource file.
2. It's very annoying to use Aspx-pages in my module since it will operate outside DotNetNuke's context. Does anybody knows an approach that allows me to use PortalModuleBase?
   I have tought about displaying a DotNetNuke page in the new window, just by referencing the Control to load. However when I do that, it will show me the full page (so with navigation bar, footer, and so on) and I actually just want to show the control. 
   Besides, I'm only able to open my Aspx-page by referencing to /DesktopModules/MyModule/Page.aspx instead of DNN's NavigateUrl or so.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: In this type of scenario, I usually create a new DNN page and give it a blank skin.  Then there is no logo, menu, footer and etc on your popup window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNN will hide all other modules on the page whenever a control (or ctl=mycontrol) is specified for the page. So,

1. You should change your code from an ASPX page to an ASCX control.
2. Add the ascx control to the Module Controls section of your module's Module Definition.
3. Use DNN's NavigateURL function to generate the link. You'll want to use one of the options where you specify the Control Key (i.e. NavigateURL("edit", "SkinSrc=[G]" + Globals.QueryStringEncode( DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.SkinInfo.RootSkin + "/" + Globals.glbHostSkinFolder + "/" + "No Skin" ))

In the above sample, "edit" is the control key you specified for the control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain the "No Skin" + "SkinSrc=[G]" stuff for me? Is "No Skin" a special parameters that tells DNN "Hey, load this control without all stuff around"?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment. Apparently the noskin piece of my advice is a bit dated... DNN used to ship with a global skin called noskin.ascx. Apparently it doesn't anymore. So, you may need to create a very simple skin that contains only a ContentPane and point towards that in the step 3. Let me know if you need help with this and I'll create one you (and others) can download.

Answer (score 0):

Why not load the edit interface in another ASCX file rather than an ASPX page? Check out http://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com for some examples in C#. It's a basic article module, but does a lot of useful things from a DNN perspective.

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks again for your answer. The thing is that my customer wants all links are shown in modal overlay windows. Is there a way how I can get rid of the stuff that is wrapped around my module? I mean; is it possible to show only 1 control on a DNN page? thx

Answer (score 0):

1. Mate for localization Aspx-pages operating outside DotNetNuke's context i suggest you to do it programatically. It will give you more control and you can debug it if some problem arises.
2. Like EfficionDave suggest use `Control Key (i.e. NavigateURL("edit", "SkinSrc=[G]" + Globals.QueryStringEncode( DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.SkinInfo.RootSkin + "/" + Globals.glbHostSkinFolder + "/" + "No Skin" ))` method

/Adnan Zameer

http://www.adnanzameer.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain the "No Skin" + "SkinSrc=[G]" stuff for me? Is "No Skin" a special parameters that tells DNN "Hey, load this control without all stuff around"?

Comment: **[G]** is used in Dotnetnuke as a placeholder for current portal location of the specific folder. **No Skin** is a skin file (No Skin.ascx) in Skin folder in path \portals. There is even a No Container.ascx in container folder if you dont want to use container. Hope it will help you out